# Python - ambiguous truth value of a series in dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am running the below code in order to detect and print out any outliers in a data set:

```
outliers = []
fields = ['Nums']

nums_df = dd.read_csv("data/mydata.csv", usecols=fields, dtype=float)

def detect_outliers(df):
    threshold = 3
    mean = np.mean(df)
    std = np.std(df)

    for index in df.iterrows():
        z_score = (index - mean) / std
        if abs(z_score) > threshold:
            outliers.append(index)
    return outliers

outliers = detect_outliers(nums_df)

print(outliers)
```

This results in the following error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().`

Adding any() or all() in the if statement fixes the error, but unsurprisingly returns an incorrect result. How am I meant to evaluate each row's truth value individuality to decide whether it meets the threshold for an outlier or not?

EDIT: Trying to use `iterseries()` on the Series returned by `iterrows()` still produces an error: `ValueError: Metadata inference failed in sub.` `AssertionError(<class 'tuple'>,)`

```
for index, series in df.iterrows():
    for s_index in series.iteritems():
        z_score = (s_index - mean) / std
        if abs(z_score) > threshold:
            outliers.append(s_index)
return outliers
```

Comment: ```iterrows()``` is a DataFrame method. ```iteritems()``` is the complementary Series method. you probably need ```for index, row in df.iterrows():``` and then operate on the row.

Comment: @HelpfulHound Even with that change, it still produces the same error. I've learned that the row is returned as a Series by `iterrows()`. I tried to use `iteritems()` on it to get to the individual values within each row but with no luck. I've edited my question to include an updated attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get an error may be that `mean` and `std` do not appear to be values, but `Series` objects.

However, in your case, you don't need to iterate over rows, just create a series using `pandas` powerful syntax.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Nums": np.random.random(10)})
mean = np.mean(df["Nums"])
std = np.std(df["Nums"])
threshold = 0.8
df["outliers"] = (df["Nums"] - mean)/std > threshold

outliers = df[df["outliers"]]
print(outliers)
```

Comment: This should work in `dask` too but please add details to your answer.